# Traverse from first node to last node using cypher language

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nodes, treenode

I have created nodes and and relationship.  I need to traverse from first node to last node. The output i expect to be displayed as 
India --> Tamil Nadu --> Chennai --> Kanchipuram --> Vandalur.

Any idea how to display this path?

Below query used to create the nodes and relationships

```
CREATE (in:place {name:"India", continent:"Asia", Language:"English"}),
    (tn:place {name:"Tamil Nadu", continent:"Asia", Language:"Tamil"}),
    (ap:place {name:"Andra Pradesh", continent:"Asia", Language:"Telugu"}),
    (ch:place {name:"Chennai", continent:"Asia", Language:"Tamil"}),
    (co:place {name:"Coimbatore", continent:"Asia", Language:"Tamil"}),
    (ka:place {name:"Kanchipuram", continent:"Asia", Language:"Tamil"}),
    (th:place {name:"Thiruvallur", continent:"Asia", Language:"Tamil"}),
    (va:place {name:"Vandalur", continent:"Asia", Language:"Tamil"}),
    (pa:place {name:"Padapai", continent:"Asia", Language:"Tamil"}),
(in)- [:parent] ->(tn),
(in)- [:parent] ->(ap),
(tn)- [:parent] ->(ch),
(tn)- [:parent] ->(co),
(ch)- [:parent] ->(ka),
(ch)- [:parent] ->(th),
(ka)- [:parent] ->(va),
(ka)- [:parent] ->(pa)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neo4j offers the `shortest path` algorithm, other graph databases may differ (see [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/execution-plans/shortestpath-planning/)).

```
MATCH (start:place { name: "India" }), (end:place { name: "Vandalur" }), p = shortestPath((start)-[:parent*]-(end)) RETURN p ;
```

If you have a clean tree structure you could also start on the target node and find all incoming `parent` relationships, which would eventually reach the root node, like this:

```
MATCH (start:place { name: "Vandalur" })<-[:parent*]-(root:place) 
RETURN start, root;
```

Comment: Thanks alot.. it works , but with little constrain is that my input should be only the last node. my output should able to travel to the source node

Comment: A graph per se does not have a root node, you are talking about a tree. You could give the root node ('India') a label to always reference it as start point of any shortest path query.

Comment: Updated my answer to handle your use case.

Comment: There should a possible way to retrieve the path to the root node, isnt it? in this scenario my input should be vandalur, and it should give me the path till india ie my start or source node.

Comment: do you know any query to handle this scenario

Comment: Hi, I thought the second query in my answer handles exactly that scenario. Did you try it? What should be different?

Comment: Does the second query fulfill your use case?

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (a:place)--(b:place)--(c:place)--(d:place)--(e:place)
RETURN a,b,c,d,e;
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21387703)

Comment: Thank you.. but is there any method to find the parent or first node by inputting only the last node. Irrespective of any type of relation, can i get the path of first and last node?